# Problems with Psychonauts and the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, package-management, downloads, internet-connection

I decided to buy the Psychonauts PC game from the Ubuntu Software Center. Now, my laptop is practically empty, with only my OS and a few bits and bobs installed. The download for Psychonauts took about 6 hours, and I waited patiently for it to download the 4.4 GB. Now, however, it comes up with something to the effect of "The packages cannot be downloaded. Check for Internet connection problems."

I don't know if it had downloaded the files to anywhere that I could access, or is there no way but to spend another 6 hours and hope for the best? I've never had this problem whilst downloading or installing anything else, and it will only redirect me towards redownloading the whole thing when I try! Any help would be much appreciated.

**Note:**

After trying to install the previous packages with Synaptic and failing to run Psychonauts, I found that `sudo apt-get install psychonauts` would work, but was getting `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11 Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/)`. Rebooting and running Terminal directly after start-up seemed to fix this and I am currently downloading Psychonauts through it at the same speed as that of USC. Possible work-around for my first time using commands?

Comment: Actually, I think it shouldn't redownload the whole thing. When you have a stable internet connection, just try to install it again from software-center. It should continue with what it has.

Comment: Nope - it does start again from scratch, and my connection is solid as a rock. Is there anywhere the Software Center stores its completed/partial packages so that I could try from there?

Comment: No, you can't use these files. For me the download just took an hour. Very strange. If the problem persists, contact Ubuntu support.

Comment: Okay then - I think that's my next course of action. Thanks very much for your help, I haven't been running Ubuntu long (2 days, in fact) and I'm still very confused!

Comment: What country are you from? I'm wondering if this may be an issue with the repos for that country.

Comment: I'm from the UK. Everything seems to work fine for any other downloads on the USC, just Psychonauts that I was having a problem with.

Answer (score 1):

You only course of action is to re-download the game. If you continue having the problem you should contact [Ubuntu Payment Service](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pay) support.

The error you describe in your note means that you had another application open that was working on the package management (like update manager or USC). You can only use one at a time.